# How to go about replacing sport climbing bolts?

Tags: gear, safety, rock-climbing, sport-climbing

There has been handful discussions about How to fix a bolt on a climbing route. But there seldom any point made about How the one should go about when removing/replacing the bolts.

- When to decide in favor of replacing the bolts, considering the crucial part bolts play in climbing?
- How to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the UK this is controlled/coordinated by the [BMC](https://www.thebmc.co.uk/).

They publish an extensive guide on how and when to do this [Bolt Guidance Document](https://www.thebmc.co.uk/bmcNews/media/u_content/File/equipment_advice/bolt_funds/Users_guideLR.pdf).

There is also a working group, coordinator and they even pay for new bolts. There are lot's of issues around this, the document goes into a lot of detail these. The most important one (in the context of your question) is.....

---

> ### When to replace bolts
>
> (sic: Bolts do fail but not very often).....After all when was the
>   last time you heard of a bolt failing? Well it  does very occasionally
>   happen and recorded cases suggest in some  situations that are hard to
>   predict. So what factors should we take into  account?
>
> **Rock quality**
>
> Like any other form of protection, a bolt is only as good as the rock
>   it is placed  in.....Always remember that the erosion that creates our
>   crags has not halted. The  weather and particularly cliff vegetation
>   has great capacity to loosen and lever  off even very large lumps of
>   rock. Once sound placements have been known  to change as the rock
>   around them unexpectedly crumbles.
>
> **Depth & Position of Bolt**
>
> Bolts placed close to edges will have a reduced strength; 200mm is
>   often  quoted as a minimum clearance distance. Unfortunately bulging
>   limestone  doesn’t usually accommodate bolts being placed with that
>   allowable distance.  Likewise, bolts placed close to cracks, pockets
>   or other discontinuities may  well be reduced in strength.
>
> **Evidence of Corrosion (Rust)**
>
> ....Just because a bolt is rusty it doesn’t mean it is dramatically
>   weakened.  However, if it is rusty it has lost some metal and
>   consequently some of its  holding capacity. It is not unknown for the
>   nut to be of a different metal and to  have corroded so that it no
>   longer holds the hanger in place. Bolts where the  hanger is fresh and
>   shiny but the bolt itself is rusty may suffer from a particular  form
>   of corrosion and have been known to break with the lightest of load.
>   It  makes sense to inspect bolts that are placed in drainage lines.
>   Unfortunately  the wettest place part of a bolt is in the hole and
>   behind the hanger making  inspection difficult.
>
> **Accidental Unclipping**
>
> Hangers or eyes ideally should be of a size that they don’t allow the
>   karabiner  to snag in such a way that the gate can be forced open and
>   unclip. Correct  orientation of the karabiner gate away from the
>   direction of travel also helps  avoid this.
>
> **Spinning Hangers**
>
> Hangers can spin because the bolt has moved in its seating or because
>   the  securing nut has become loose. If there is evidence of the former
>   then the bolt  is likely to be unsafe. If the latter is the cause then
>   the nut should be  immediately retightened. The leverage and wear
>   caused by a weighted  hanger rotating on the bolt body can give rise
>   to weakening of the unit due to  the formation of microscopic
>   fractures.
>
> **Old Bolts**
>
> Despite the number of renewal programmes there are still many old
>   bolts out  there, especially ones used to protect blank sections on
>   80’s trad routes.  Common sense dictates that bolts have a limited
>   useful life and it is always  worth consulting the guidebook to see
>   when the route was first done or, if the  gear has been replaced, when
>   that might have been done. Whilst stainless  steel products are likely
>   to be good for a lot longer, experience has shown that  many bolts
>   placed in the past are dangerously weak after 10 years. Some  early
>   staples had no notches on their legs making them prone to pulling out 
>   relatively easily if an outwards force is applied.
>
> **Wobbly or Damaged Bolts - Mechanical or Glue-Ins**
>
> It makes sense to doubt the holding power of any bolt that wobbles in
>   its hole!  With glue-in bolts a problem can arise if the drill dust is
>   not thoroughly cleaned  out of the hole or if it was placed in a damp
>   hole. Some wobbly glue-ins have  been found to take quite high loads
>   but it’s probably not sensible to test these  with your own weight!
>
> **Unset Glue**
>
> Glues have to be mixed properly. Failure to do as instructed can
>   result in the  mixture not curing, or hardening as was designed and
>   not holding the bolt in  place. Several serious accidents have
>   happened when climbers have come  across new bolts and attempted the
>   route without checking the glue has set.
>
> **Deteriorating Glue**
>
> Like the bolts themselves the glue can and will deteriorate with time
>   though for  appropriate glues this should be a very slow process.
>   However, there is  anecdotal evidence that some inappropriate glues
>   have been used, that are  not suitable for the alkaline solutions
>   likely to be encountered in limestone  rocks. Unfortunately this could
>   mean that once sound bolts become less so,  perhaps as little as two
>   years after placement.
>
> **Worn Belay Bolts**
>
> If top-roping a route the climber can always arrange slings so that
>   both bolts  are weighted. This is good practice and climbers should be
>   discouraged from  top roping with the rope directly through the belay
>   bolts, as significant wear on  the eye can quickly result.
>
> **Home Made Hangers**
>
> Various types of bolt hanger were homemade during the 1950s and 60s. 
>   Usually these were simple angle iron (or aluminium alloy) with holes
>   drilled in  each side. A few may still be encountered on old aid
>   routes today but  generally they are now of little relevance and most
>   have been superseded by  modern bolts or other forms of protection
>
> **Stress Corrosion cracking**
>
> Although there is no evidence of this type of attack occurring in the
>   UK, a  number of bolts have failed by stress corrosion cracking (SCC)
>   in Thailand  and Cayman Brac so it’s worth being aware of it if you’re
>   going sport climbing  in the tropics. SCC can occur in stainless
>   steels in aqueous chloride solutions  (e.g., seawater) so the bolts on
>   sea cliffs appear to be most susceptible.  Luckily for us, there is a
>   temperature (~50°C) below which it doesn’t occur  (except in very
>   acidic conditions) so it shouldn’t be a problem in the UK until 
>   global warming really kicks in. The corrosion is very localised and
>   takes the  form of cracks that can penetrate through the metal,
>   reducing its strength to  almost zero. These cracks can be very fine
>   and difficult to detect on the  surface and impossible to see how far
>   they penetrate

---

There is also a [part II](https://www.thebmc.co.uk/Download.aspx?id=216). This goes into details on how to go about actually replacing the bolts.

When it comes to removing the bolts, it depends....You can sometimes unscrew them, sometimes the need chopping. TBH, it doesn't matter as you should drill a new hole, etc. for any new bolts anyway. Just make it obvious that the old bolts should not be used/remove them as best you can.

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing from how you phrased your question that you are really interested in how rebolting, specifically bolt removal, is performed. I have never rebolted anything, but the ASCA (American Safe Climbing Association) has pretty thorough articles for people interested in learning how to rebolt climbs [here](http://www.safeclimbing.org/education/howtorebolt.htm).

It goes over the following topics in very good detail:

- Determining candidates for rebolting (types of bolts used, condition of bolts)
- Procedure and equipment to remove old bolts
- What hardware (specific bolts and hangers) to replace with
- The actual rebolting procedure